# What is the red and white bar on the status screen?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I've been playing RDR2 on PS4 for about a week now. When I hit the down directional button, to toggle the radar size, it also shows various health and stamina meters. At the very bottom of the screen there is a horizontal bar with a cowboy hat in the middle.

What is this called, and what does it do/show? Right now mine is red on the left and white to the right. I'd like to research this but nothing came up on Google the other day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the Honor Bar. [Here](http://www.powerpyx.com/red-dead-redemption-2-how-to-increase-honor-level/) is a good article that explains it:

> In Red Dead Redemption 2 you can increase your honor level to unlock new clothing and get access to the missable honor mission...
>
> To keep track of your honor press [d-pad down] and check the bar [at] the bottom of the screen. If the bar is on the left (red) it means dishonorable. To the right (white is honorable).
>
> **Benefits from increased Honor**
>
> You can see your honor benefits in the Pause Menu under Player, General, Honor.
>
> - Rank 1: Better loot from corpses.
> - Rank 2: 10% off in all stores.
> - Rank 3: New Outfits become available.
> - Rank 4: Get access to optional chapter 6 honor mission ‘Do Not Seek Absolution’.
> - Rank 5: 25% off in all stores.
> - Rank 6: New Outfits become available.
> - Rank 7: 50% off in all stores.
> - Rank 8: Nothing, just peace of mind that you’re the most honorable gunslinger in the wild west.

Comment: This answer addresses exactly what I asked, and I don't think it should be downvoted.

Comment: @Mark Can you not see the other answer?

Comment: Yes, but the provided link offers much more info.

Comment: @CarlosOrtega You should then include the information from the source into your answer. Otherwise, this answer would be obsolete if the link were to ever go bad

Comment: I've gone ahead and added the missing information.

Answer (score 10):

Pretty sure the game explains our when it first appears, but the game can also throw multiple notifications at you and it's easy to miss.

The bar is your honour - you start neutral,  and then as you do good or bad deeds it will move appropriately. Honour then affects how people react to you.

Comment: Good is the white side, red is the bad side.  You get a cheevo for maxing out one side or the other.